# Am I paying Double fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, testnet

On testnet I sent a [transaction](https://tbtc.blockr.io/tx/info/0ce8fcb677432004c2da94efc7b4526ef0cdcccbbb37b0019a53fc1e2e7f39b7)

I believe this was for TBTC1.000 and a 0.0001 fee: i.e. inputs - outputs = 0.0001.

When I try to claim the transaction I am only allowed to claim 1 - 0.001. If I claim (what I expect to be) the full amount (TBTC1.000) I receive an err #26.
If I claim TBTC0.9999 everything works

I presume I'm doing something wrong, and would be happy to understand what that is.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: 1) blockr.io isn't showing the full transaction by default. Click Raw instead of Trade. 2) Why wouldn't you pay fees twice? They're two different transactions, no?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the fee structure. If the rule is: pay a fee to send  and one for a receive that's OK. I thought that only the sender pays - if I misunderstood, then I need to adjust my thinking. If you like - I have the full decodes...

Comment: You mean 'inputs - outputs' right?

Answer (score 2):

OK - now I understand. The fee comes from the second txn. I sent 1.000 but when it's spent I need another fee.